# Make tar from /dev/stdin file

Tags: tar, devices, stdin

What I'm looking for is a way to pass in arbitrary data through STDIN, and have it get tar'd up as if its a normal file.

I tried this

```
$ echo test | tar -cf test.tar /dev/stdin
```

and that gives me a `test.tar` file with the contents `dev/stdin`. The `stdin` file is a link to `/proc/self/fd/0`.

What I want instead is for `dev/stdin` inside the TAR file to be a regular file with the text `test` inside. A similar thing happens with:

```
$ tar -cf test.tar <(echo test)
```

but the names are different.

Is this doable?

Comment: Does it need to be a tar file specifically? Other archiving tools (ar, zip) might do this but I don't know of a tar implementation that doesn't preserve device files.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I'd prefer it to be a tar, but the real goal is to create a sparse file that's archived so it's portable. If this worked the way I wanted, the command I'd use would be `pv /dev/sda | tar -cSf disk.tar /dev/stdin`

Comment: `echo test ¦ tar -cf test.tar -`

Comment: i `tar`d streams. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151009/how-to-convince-tar-etc-to-archive-block-device-contents/151057

Comment: anyway, `shitar` might not be what you want, but you may get a clue there. i tried to touch on basic format requisites enough for me to understand later.

Comment: @mikeserv Interesting take on this problem, but I'm looking for a way to do it with then built in `tar`

Comment: i think you might wanna look closer at that link. the whole of `shitar` is provided - its a `sh`ell function. anyway, that question asks better than this does how to do what you want to do. @slm - wanna consider duping it? i dont remember how to do all that stackexchange stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want here. The problem with your approach is that `tar` deals in files and directory trees, which you're not providing it with commands such as this:

```
$ echo test | tar -cf test.tar /dev/sdtin
```

Even when you attempt to "wrap" your strings in temporary files using subshells such as this:

```
$ tar -cf test.tar <(echo test)
```

You can see your content is still being TAR'ed up using these temporary file descriptors:

```
$ tar tvf test.tar
lr-x------ vagrant/vagrant   0 2018-08-04 23:52 dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[102734]
```

If you're intent is just to compress strings, you need to get them into a file context. So you'd need to do something like this:

```
$ echo "test" > somefile && tar -cf /tmp/test.tar somefile
```

You can see the file's present inside of the TAR file:

```
$ tar tvf /tmp/test.tar
-rw-rw-r-- vagrant/vagrant   5 2018-08-05 00:00 somefile
```

#### Replicating data using tar

Most that have been working with Unix for several years will likely have seen this pattern:

```
$ (cd /; tar cf - .)|(cd /mnt/newroot; tar pxvf -)
```

I used to use this all the time to replicate data from one location to another. You can use this over SSH as well. Other methods are discussed in this U&L Q&A titled: [clone root directory tree using busybox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84964/clone-root-directory-tree-using-busybox/84966#84966).

#### Backing up /

There's also this method if you're intent is to back up the entier HDD:

```
$ sudo tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

#### References

- [4 Ways to Back Up Your Entire Hard Drive on Linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/back-up-entire-hard-drive-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a tar file as a stream if you know the final size of what you want to stream (in bytes). It is then a matter of creating the initial 512 byte header before the data stream, and a trailing padding after it. Though it does depend on the exact variant of `tar` file, since there are a couple of different file formats. The following steps might work for you:

1. create a hole file of the same size as the data stream

   `$ dd if=/dev/zero of=mystream bs=1 count=0 seek=$SIZE`

   Note that `mystream` is now a "hole" file that doesn't actually occupy disk space even though it appears to have the same size, $SIZE, as the data stream.
2. use `tar` to create a header for a file named `mystream` of that size

   `$ tar cf - mystream | head -c 512 > header`

   Note that `tar` will want to create a file without hole, so it's therefore important to discard everything except the first 512 bytes. Then remove the hole file, so to avoid it being accidentally copied.

   `$ rm mystream`
3. create a padding trailer to fill out to a number of 512 blocks.

   `$ head -c $((echo "scale=0; 512 - $SIZE % 512" | bc )) > trailer`
4. make the tar stream of $STREAM (of size $SIZE) with header and trailer

   `$ cat header $STREAM trailer`

   Note, you'd probably want to stream that to something other than stdout.

Comment: gnu `tar` does have some kind of `--sparse` switch or something, but you also need to be careful about the blocking at the *tail* of the file - if it doesnt line up to a null padded block the `tar` will be technically trash *(not actually a `tar`)* but gnu `tar` tends to take that in stride and process it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you can use the `=(...)` form of process substitution which uses a temporary file instead of a pipe. With GNU `tar`'s `--transform` option, you can change the name of the archive member:

```
tar --transform='s/.*/test-file/' -zcf file.tar.gz =(echo test)
```

Would create a  `file.tar.gz` with one `test-file` member with permissions 0600 and content `test\n`.

With `bash` (or `zsh`), you could do:

```
tar --transform='s/.*/test-file/' -zchf file.tar.gz /dev/stdin <<< "$(echo test)"
```

Here-strings also use temp files in those shells. Note however that command substitution strips *every* trailing newline character and adds *one* back and in `bash` would strip NUL bytes.